# In Android WebView, possible to view headers before each request?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In Android, WebView - as pages are loaded - on user navigation and auto-redirects -
can I view the headers before each request?

I just want to view the headers and let the request proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create a WebViewClient to do the request with a client that lets you do the requests and parse the headers response, like Volley:

```
private WebViewClient getWebViewClient() {
    return new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final android.webkit.WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            android.util.Log.d("Headers", "New request: " + request);
            if (request.getRequestHeaders() != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> entry : request.getRequestHeaders().entrySet()) {
                    android.util.Log.d("Headers", "Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            doVolleyRequest(view, request.getUrl().toString());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
            android.util.Log.d("Headers", "New url: " + url);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.d("onPageStarted", url);
        }
    };
}

private void doVolleyRequest(final WebView webView, String url) {
    StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, response, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.headers;
            if (responseHeaders != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> entry : responseHeaders.entrySet()) {
                    android.util.Log.d("Headers", "Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    queue.add(getRequest);
}
```

And assigning it to the webview before loading the url:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(getWebViewClient());
String url = "https://***********";
doVolleyRequest(webView, url); // webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Keep in mind that you'll need to add volley to the gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

By override of the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method it logs the request headers and assigns the response html to the webview so that the webview doesn't have to do the url loading itself.